# Problems using inheritance with drag and drop in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have a usercontrol that I want to implement a drag and drop interface on, here are the vital parts of the implementation, and this works fine:

XML-file to the usercontrol to be draggable:

```
<UserControl 
         ...default xmlns...
         MouseLeftButtonDown="Control_MouseLeftButtonDown">
         ...GUI-ELEMENTS in the control...
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class DragableControl : UserControl
{
    private void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

XML-file to the usercontrol which will be able to accept a drag and drop operation:

```
<Usercontrol 
         ...default xmlns...>
    <Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop">
         ... GUI elements in the grid....
    </Grid> 
</Usercontrol>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class DropClass: UserControl
{
    private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (DragableControl)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragableControl));
        if(control != null)
        {
            //do something
        }        
    }
}
```

To be able to create different usercontrols which have drag and drop functionality, I creates a base class, BaseDragableUserControl, which at the moment contains nothing, but inherits from usercontrol.

Code:

```
public class BaseDragableUserControl: UserControl
{
}
```

I change my code (both xaml and code):

```
 public partial class DragableControl : UserControl
```

I also changes the class for receiving  to this:

```
public partial class DropClass: UserControl
{
    private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var control =(BaseDragableUserControl)e.Data.GetData(typeof(BaseDragableUserControl));
        if(control != null)
        {
            //do something
        }        
    }
}
```

But the **control** variable is always Null. I guess that the getdata in the DragEventsArgs does not like inheritance. Is there a way to achieve this? To make it possible to use a base class for a drag and drop class?

Comment: Did you copy your code incorrectly because i don't see any class actually inheriting from BaseDragableUserControl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing `this` when you initiate the drag/drop, create one of the standard containers for that purpose.  Specifically:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject("myFormat", this), DragDropEffects.Move);
```

and then now you know to expect a specific kind of data:

```
var control =(BaseDragableUserControl)e.Data.GetData("myFormat");
```